# Conditional rendering of the data template in XAML

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a list of text blocks, that may include urls inside, smth like:

- Build failed, see more here: http://...
- Build succeeded
- App http://myapp/ cannot be started, see more here: http://...

I need to display this (endless) list in a UWP app. Considering this list can be used in multiple views inside the app, I made it a common template:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="ListItemTemplate" TargetType="ItemsControl">
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding image_url}"/>
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding status}"/>
    </Grid>
  </ControlTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In this template links are treated like regular text (which is expected). As I understand, to make links work I need to wrap them into `<HyperLink>` tag, but I cannot do this in template, because I don't know where exactly links will be and how many of them will appear.

Is there any way to implement some renderer method, that could generate item's body (`<TextBlock>`) in code, processing passed value?

Probably converter could help me, but if I understand correctly, it only accept value from binding, and I need to reference whole instance.

**UPD**: Expanding solution from the accepted answer:

**Resource dictionary**:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns:resources="using:NamespaceWithTextBlockExt">
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="ListItemTemplate" TargetType="ItemsControl">
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding image_url}"/>
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" resources:TextBlockExt.XAMLText="{Binding Text}"/>
    </Grid>
  </ControlTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Processor somewhere in your project**:

```
public static class TextBlockExt
{
    public static String GetXAMLText(TextBlock obj)
    {
        return (String)obj.GetValue(XAMLTextProperty);
    }

    public static void SetXAMLText(TextBlock obj, String value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(XAMLTextProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert raw string from ViewModel into formatted text in a TextBlock: 
    /// 
    /// @"This <Bold>is a test <Italic>of the</Italic></Bold> text."
    /// 
    /// Text will be parsed as XAML TextBlock content. 
    /// 
    /// See WPF TextBlock documentation for full formatting. It supports spans and all kinds of things. 
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty XAMLTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("XAMLText", typeof(String), typeof(TextBlockExt),
                                             new PropertyMetadata("", XAMLText_PropertyChanged));

    private static void XAMLText_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is TextBlock)
        {
            var ctl = d as TextBlock;

            try
            {
                //  XAML needs a containing tag with a default namespace. We're parsing 
                //  TextBlock content, so make the parent a TextBlock to keep the schema happy. 
                //  TODO: If you want any content not in the default schema, you're out of luck. 
                var value = e.NewValue;

                var strText = String.Format(@"<TextBlock xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"">{0}</TextBlock>", e.NewValue);

                TextBlock parsedContent = Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlReader.Load(strText) as TextBlock;

                //  The Inlines collection contains the structured XAML content of a TextBlock
                ctl.Inlines.Clear();

                var inlines = parsedContent.Inlines.ToList();
                parsedContent.Inlines.Clear();

                //  UI elements are removed from the source collection when the new parent 
                //  acquires them, so pass in a copy of the collection to iterate over. 
                ctl.Inlines.Concat(inlines);
                inlines.ForEach(x => ctl.Inlines.Add(x));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Error in Ability.CAPS.WPF.UIExtensions.TextBlock.XAMLText_PropertyChanged: {0}", ex.Message));
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure this is the best way, but it works. I just need to preprocess bound value and wrap all URLs into hyperlink tags:

`"App <Hyperlink NavigateUri=\"http://app/\">myapp</Hyperlink>"`

I assume this should work with any other content, like `<InlineUIContainer>`

Comment: It should work with any content that can be a child of `TextBlock`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an attached behavior that parses a string as XAML using [`XamlReader.Load(Stream)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590388(v=vs.110).aspx), and adds the resulting control to the target control. [Here's one I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361952/424129) which does it with `TextBlock` content, which can include `Hyperlink`. That's for WPF not UWP; there may be some differences.

Yours would have to do a little additional work: It would take a non-XAML string, and before parsing as XAML it would have to find URLs and replace them with XAML `Hyperlink` elements in the string. Then you'd parse that.

It would be cleaner to put that second part in a value converter. Call it `HyperLinksToXAMLConverter`:

```
<TextBlock
    local:XAMLText="{Binding status, Converter={StaticResource HyperLinksToXAML}}"
    />
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I tested this solution and it allows me to modify content and show hyperlinks. As mentioned - code should be adjusted slightly.

Comment: @ragzovskii Awesome. Can you add the UWP version of the code to your Q, or edit it into my A? I'll approve the edit.